# Can't get passenger to serve pages (steps I used inside)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache2, passenger

I have been struggling to get passenger to run my Rails/Rack apps.

Steps I used (as root):

Clean Debian 6 installation

- aptitude install apache2, (Ruby
  requirements taken from RVM),
  git-core, curl, (and some more
  packages too I guess)
- getting rvm installed (system wide)
- installing ruby 1.9.2-p180, and
  setting it to be used as default
- installing passenger gem, and
  running the apache2 module
  installation (getting apache2
  prequisites along the way)
- creating 
  /etc/apache2/mods-available/passenger.load
  and placing:

> LoadModule
>       passenger_module ... (the one
>       printed after apache2 passenger
>       module got installed)

- creating

  /etc/apache2/mods-available/passenger.conf
  and placing:

> PassengerRuby ...
>
> PassengerRoot ... (the ones printed after apache2
>       passenger module got installed)

- ap2enmod passenger (and getting apache restarted afterwards)

> mkdir /var/www
>
> setting /var/www to be user: root, group: www-data
>
> creating /var/www/testapp and copying my rails app there
>
> creating /etc/apache2/sites-available/testapp and placing in there:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName localhost/testapp
     DocumentRoot /var/www/testapp/public
     <Directory /var/www/testapp/public>
         AllowOverride all
        Options -MultiViews
     </Directory>
  </VirtualHost>
```

- ap2ensite testapp
- bundle install from within /var/www/testapp
- /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

After opening in the browser: localhost/testapp I can only see my rails app structure (it didnt fire the page)

I don't know what I have done wrong. It seems to be pretty much okay. I am concerned about file permissions, groups and so on, although I have no clue how should I set these up. How should permissions be structured? Apart from that, anything else that looks suspicious?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ServerName can't have slashes in it. Just make ServerName localhost, and go to http://localhost to visit your site.

If you need multiple websites deployed on localhost, you can do that, but you need to follow the extra steps here:

http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#deploying_rails_to_sub_uri

Comment: Oh. Thanks, indeed it ran it!